# Is there a place to put a category import statement so all classes see it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, global, categories

I have an Objective-C category of UIColor that I would like to "import" everywhere in my project.  But instead of using the #import to every class that needs it I was told there was a way to set it up so all classes can see it.  Anyone know how this is accomplished?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add that import to the precompiled header file (*.pch) in your project - that way it will be imported to any implementation file automatically.

Comment: Make sure that it is placed inside of the `#ifdef __OBJC__` check!

Comment: I placed it in the check.  Thanks Joe.