# How To Use macro without importing the .h file in the Xcode

Tags: xcode, macros, import

Someday, I found one issue in the Xcode.
I used one macro for anywhere I want, the problem is I was't  imported one .h file where the macro defined, in fact  I can use this macro normally.
Can somebody  help me?

Comment: What is the problem you try to solve? Circular imports? Then use [`@class`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191487/objective-c-forward-class-declaration). Or do you want do save typing work? Then look for the [precompiled header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707590/is-there-a-place-to-put-a-category-import-statement-so-all-classes-see-it/6707627#6707627)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import to the precompiled header file `*.pch` in your project, that way it will be imported to any implementation file automatically. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707590/is-there-a-place-to-put-a-category-import-statement-so-all-classes-see-it/6707627#6707627)

Comment: Though it's best not to mess with the .pch file unless you need that macro in 90% of your controllers).

Answer (score 0):

defining any macro inside `<your project>.pch` will work for entire app automatically. You can find this auto-generated file inside `Supporting Files` in your project directory.

In `.pch` file you should declare all those constants and and macros you are using throughout the app (not recommended if you are not using these variables in most of the `viewcontrollers`) and in most of the `viewControllers`

for example:

```
// frameworks
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// a category
#import "UIColor+custom.h"

// a class
#import "aClass.h"

 // a macro
#define kAppFont @"TrebuchetMS"

// a global object
NSInteger myInteger; 

// a macro with case
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```